# What is the variable "a" in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

In using the `scale` filter with ffmpeg, I see many examples similar to this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -vf scale="'if(gt(a,4/3),320,-2)':'if(gt(a,4/3),-2,240)'" output.mov
```

What does the variable `a` signify?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the ffmpeg [scale options](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Options-1) docs.

> **a** The same as iw / ih

where

> **iw** Input Width   **ih** Input Height

Comment: Yes! But that was well hidden in the documentation, imo, and should be included in the wiki page "Scaling (resizing) with ffmpeg".

Comment: @coco The wiki is only to supplement the documentation. However, anyone can edit the wiki, so feel free to add it if you like.

Comment: The ffmpeg documentation devs should clearly create a custom search on their website. How do they expect us to visit a long-scrollable page and CTRL+F for "a" ?

Comment: Luckily, they are using jQuery. As a custom hack, you can open your DevTools and search for relevant DOM nodes with this command `$('samp').filter((index, el) => el.innerText.match(/\ba\b/))`. Then you can right-click-select "Scroll into view" from the Elements panel.

Answer (score 1):

My guess after reading https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Scaling%20(resizing)%20with%20ffmpeg is that a is the aspect ratio of the input file.

The example given on the webpage gives you an idea how to use it:

> Sometimes there is a need to scale the input image in such way it fits
>   into a specified rectangle, i.e. if you have a placeholder (empty
>   rectangle) in which you want to scale any given image. This is a
>   little bit tricky, since you need to check the original aspect ratio,
>   in order to decide which component to specify and to set the other
>   component to -1 (to keep the aspect ratio). For example, if we would
>   like to scale our input image into a rectangle with dimensions of
>   320x240, we could use something like this:
>
> ```
> ffmpeg -i input.jpg -vf scale="'if(gt(a,4/3),320,-1)':'if(gt(a,4/3),-1,240)'"
> output_320x240_boxed.png
> ```

Answer (score 1):

In the ffmpeg wiki "[Scaling (resizing) with ffmpeg](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Scaling%20(resizing)%20with%20ffmpeg)", they use this example:

```
ffmpeg -i input.jpg -vf scale="'if(gt(a,4/3),320,-1)':'if(gt(a,4/3),-1,240)'" output.png
```

The purpose of the `gt(a,4/3)` is, as far as I can tell, to determine the orientation (portrait or landscape) of the video (or image, in this case).

This wouldn't work for some strange aspect ratios (7:6, for an example, where `gt(a,4/3)` would incorrectly turn false.

It seems to me better to use the height and width of the video, so the above line would instead be:

```
ffmpeg -i input.jpg -vf scale="'if(gt(iw,ih),320,-1)':'if(gt(iw,ih),-1,240)'" output.png
```